# SOC (state of charge of batteries) for LiFePO4

Tags: arduino, batteries, battery-charging, charging, discharge

**I am trying to find the state of charge (SOC) of some batteries**

- I have 3 LiFePO4 batteries, these are the ones I have purchased:

  *https://www.ampsplus.co.uk/ampsplus-14500-3-2v-500mah-battery-button*
- I have them connected in **parallel**. For each battery I can measure their **individual voltage** and I can **individually discharge** each one through a resistor.
- The two methods I have found online to find the SOC (state of charge) of each battery are called coulomb counting and the second one is a voltage look up table.

**Columb counting**

This method involves integrating the current over time to find out how much charge is given to the batteries.

1. This only measures the difference in state of charge. Since you do not know how much charge is already in each battery you cant actually find the state of charge, how do you overcome this problem?
2. I only know how much current is going into the whole parallel connection and not into each battery, so that gives the SOC change across all of them and not each one. Is there a safe way to find the current going into each battery. Do we even need to find the current going into each one, if they are in parallel would they not just distribute this evenly between them?

**Voltage look up table**

This seems to be the easier method. If you have a graph of voltage VS SOC you can find how much charge is in each battery by simply measure the voltage on each battery and then comparing to the voltage values from the graph/look up table - The issue is

1. I looked at the data sheet as shown in the link and I cannot find anything like this. Therefore I would would need to find this myself. This leaves the question of how I could possibly do this?
2. When I do find this graph, then can I use the look up table for all the batteries, as in are the differences between them negligible enough to use the same graph for all or would I need to produce a different graph for each one?

**I am thankful for any help and appreciate your time reading this.**

To add: I would not like to use any pre made BMS systems online as I am trying to learn about this. I am currently using

- Arduino nano every
- SMPS for DC-DC conversion it can be a buck or boost
- I have designed a circuit for the batteries that can measure their voltages and discharge them individually.

Answering some questions ( I will edit this later with answers and everything If I am able to obtain them )

Just a note Russel, when you say 1%, what exactly do you refer to ?

To give an idea, this project uses an SMPS, Arduino and a circuit board.

Q1 - The current is measured using the ina219 current sensor. These values are taken every 1s and stored using the Arduino to an SD card.

Q2 - The batteries are connected in parallel using power cables. Each battery is in a circuit board which is this:

[image]

Using the relay, I can stop charging it and measure the voltage of each cell seperately and discharge them. It has an opto to isolate the cell from connections a relay to change pins for measuring and a pos and neg port which are used to connect the batteries together. The mosfet and resistor are only used when dischargining.

Q3 - For the integration, what I am doing is on the Arduino it collects the current measured every second. so its currentx1 second and I just add all the current basically since that find the area, AKA integration. ( yes it does assume the current is constant for that one second but the current is regulated by a PID controller so it has a very very small error).

As for SOH(state of health), temperature etc I will focus on these later, I am trying to implement SOC, balancing and charging first.

Comment: For LFP, the voltage lookup isn't all that useful : it's a very flat curve around 3.2V. If 3.6V is 100% and 2.5V is 0%, you'll find 3.3V is about 90% and 3.1V is about 10%. Between those ... good luck. Coulomb counting works.

Comment: @user_1818839 I can measure the voltage up to a mV. I think this should at least be enough to differentiate between 95%, 85% 80% etc so 5% increments. I have collected some data of the voltage of the batteries e,g 3.301 etc. Additionally you are correct in saying that I am treating 3.6V as max voltage and 2.5V is lowest voltage.

Comment: I am open to any suggestions on some algorithm or a method of determining the SOC. I am not trying to find the most complex method just something that atleast gives me something which is somewhat accurate.

Comment: Hi fred! If your batteries are in parallel, you can't discharge them individually. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Lithiums are not normal batteries. They can burn very intensely if mis-handled in charging or discharging.  That's why lithiums **need** a competent BMS in front of them.  If you want to DIY battery management, you can choose a lithium that has an embedded BMS (sits under the positive terminal so it makes the battery slightly taller; it's invisible to you for all practical purposes, so you get to have the fun of BMS design without the risk), or if you want to "run on bare metal", you can select a more docile chemistry such as NiMH.

Comment: @bitsmack I have a circuit designed which can do this, I can send a schematic if you would like its really simple.

Comment: @reinstate monica, I am trying to design something which can do battery balancing, SOC, SOH etc so i guess that is a BMS in itself.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica These are not normal Lithium cells. They are considerably safer, but I don't know of any LFPs with built-in BMS.

Comment: to add to what @user_1818839 said, these batteries just sort of die/stop charging/discharging when they get to a point where they might burn or melt etc, this is one of the reasons why I chose them.

Comment: @Fred sure, those goals are compatible. You can have the on-cell BMS protecting the cell itself, and also have your external circuit doing balancing.  At that point your external circuit only needs to balance.

Comment: @user_1818839 I found one effortlessly with a google search, onboard BMS and all.  And "considerably safer than normal lithium" isn't much of a recommendation lol.  Older battery tech is just safe, no "r" needed. This whole idea of "batteries catching fire" is really quite novel, and is only there due to the mad chase for energy density.

Comment: @fred 1% is probably about as good as you can achieve without very careful control of measurements. | Q1 what are you using to measure the current? (,Meter or system used, accuracy, resolution, brand) ...Q2 how are you connecting to the cells (details receiving, meter connections etc)? Q3 how are you integrating the results to get mAh - time period samples taken algorithm ... ? || Also temperature control, load heating,  other devices running ...

Comment: A voltage lookup table can be expected to be less accurate than coulomb counting and will vary with battery condition, temperature, load current and more. Properly implemented coulomb counting tells you the ACTUAL coulomb's in and out.

Comment: I see some of what I asked is given in comments on Bruce's answer.it helps greatly for ALL relevant information to be placed in the question (and ideally to be present initially if known).

Comment: Suggestion: measure cell terminal voltage when charged. Charge at say 0.1 V above this until current drops to a very small fraction - say C/20 to C/100 range. Cell is now fully charged.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Please find answers to your questions added to the bottom of the post.

Comment: I do have some concerns and I would appreciate your input. I have an issue with actually charging the battery to 3.6V. My characterization process is this. If the battery is less than 3.6V, it charges. Once it reaches 3,6V, it stops charging and rests for 10-20 seconds. Then it starts discharging until it reaches 2.5 V and repeats. I am Using constant current charging and I am charging it at 800mA

Comment: The issue is that Using constant current charging, it charges it to 3.6V, but as it stops charging it immediately falls to 3.4V. I have read online that this is due to ESR and capacitance in the batteries. I have also seen it mentioned that using a combination of constant current and constant voltage charging could allow you to reach 3.6V by using constant voltage  to charge from 3.6V and onwards. Do you have any experience or know ways I could tackle this/ if this is correct?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/13owkjr Here is a graph of mV VS time in seconds which I used to characterise the battery using the charge cycle I mentioned. You could clearly see the drop from 3.6 to 3.4V I mentioned above. Second issue is with coulomb counting, I am setting 3.6V as the 100% SOC and 2.5V as the 0% SOC point. The issue is I am assuming the current going into battery parallel is split evenly between them which is not correct. For example, I measured one battery to be 550mAh while the other one was 550mAh and nominally they should be 500mAh.

Comment: Since I cannot measure the current going into each battery individually but into the whole parallel combination, this would lead to inaccuracies. I have also noticed that the total Coulombs discharged is slightly bigger than the the coulombs used to charge the battery so there is some error there as well with the measurements.

Comment: The way I am trying to implement balancing and SOC is this. I constantly measure the voltage of each battery to check they do not go above 3.6V while charging and not below 2.5V while discharging and I discharge/charge them as required, I am top balancing them so when they are connected they need to be initially somewhere near 100% fully charged so around 3.6V. That covers balancing. For SOC, I find the initial SOC and then depending on if they are charging or discharging , I coloumb count by integrating (more like adding) the current and minus or add to the intial SOC as needed.

Comment: For Constant voltage charging, do you just artificially put a certain voltage across the battery? if so how do you determine what this voltage should be? Sorry for the spam just wanted to explain what I was doing.

Comment: How do you measure current from your shown arrangement? Is it inferred from V_bat_OC / R_losd or ???

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The current sensor measures the current, this is then connected to an analogue pin on the Arduino. The analogue pin is read every second and the current is recorded.

Comment: @fred  Your current measurement circuit does not seem to be shown (on your diagram). Presumably you have an **always connected** series sense resistopr from FET source to ground with a sense lead to the Arduno measurement ADC input connected to the drain.

Comment: For as accurate as possible ADC measurement it is ESSENTIAL that the ground side of the sense resistor and the analog ground of the processor are connected by a PCB track with no other current carrying conductor branching off it. What sense resistor do you use?  What is ADC Vref and how many ADC bits. I have seen significant ADC errors due to ground return practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since you do not know how much charge is already in each battery you
> cant actually find the state of charge, how do you overcome this
> problem?

Fully charge the battery, then 'count coulombs' until voltage shows it is nearly empty. This can be used as a reference for future partial charge and discharge, but may have to be repeated occasionally if the battery isn't normally fully cycled.

> Do we even need to find the current going into each one, if they are
> in parallel would they not just distribute this evenly between them?

If the cells are all the same (part number, age, measured capacity etc.) then they should share the current approximately equally *until they reach full charge*. If the capacities are not close to equal they should share the current according to their individual capacities.

When an LiFePO4 reaches full charge its current draw decreases (compared to other cells at the same voltage). Since one cell is bound to get there first, the others will then be charging at higher current towards the end. Provided the cells are well matched and the charging current is not too high this shouldn't be a problem.

Note that any excess resistance between the cells will cause some to receive more charging current than others. Therefore they should be connected together with soldered or welded low resistance straps, *not* put in battery holders.

> Voltage look up table... I looked at the data sheet as shown in the
> link and I cannot find anything like this

That may be because a voltage lookup table is not useful with LiFePO4, because the discharge curve is very flat over most of the cycle.

> When I do find this graph, then can I use the look up table for all
> the batteries, as in are the differences between them negligible
> enough to use the same graph for all or would I need to produce a
> different graph for each one?

Once you find that graph you will probably understand why it won't work. The differences between brands may be 'negligible', but so is the voltage change. [Here](https://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/Shockli%2014500%20AA%20LiFePO4%20650mAh%20%28Purple%29%20UK.html) are some example discharge curves at various currents:-

[image]

Note the truncated Y scale. At low to moderate current drain the voltage drops very slowly until the battery is nearly empty, and could easily be swamped by current draw variations.

Comment: I just want to clarify about finding the reference point to do coulomb counting.  You mention fully charging the battery. I am currently charging the batteries using a synchronous buck which is connected to 5V input. The reason I am doing this is because I can control the inductor current which is basically the current going into the battery and this is 250mA. I assume to find the reference point you would need to do constant voltage charging ? to see when the current falls really low indicating it hit 100% SOC?

Comment: this is the charging and discharging of the cell: https://prnt.sc/13nhilr (y axis is mV and x axis is time 

it reaches 3.6V and then goes down to around 3.4V due to the ESR and capacitance of the cell. The manufacturer states you should not charge it over 3.6V. I assume that to reach 100% SOC you might go over that?

Comment: Looking at the discharge (happens after 3.4V until 2.5V) it is actually not as flat as one might think?

Comment: Apologies, for the excess I am just confused as to how to " fully charge" the battery to get a reference point for 100% SOC. Assuming I fully charge it, I now begin to discharge it, how would I know when it reaches 0 SOC and how do I do this before killing the battery ( below 2.5V). These batteries are very sensitive to over and undervolting.

Comment: Taking a battery down to 0% charge is sure way to kill it. Your discharge graph is missing important information. What is the time scale? What was the discharge current? 3.6V is actually higher than necessary. 3.5V is plenty, and 3.4V is enough if you don't mind waiting https://lygte-info.dk/info/BatteryLiFePO4Charging%20UK.html

Comment: The time scale is in seconds so that cycle there took around 2.7 hours. The discharge current is set to 250mA  as well, this is controlled by a PID so it hovers around it and not constantly around 250mA. The thing is that although it reaches 3.6V it isnt actually 3.6V. around 0.2V is lost due to the ESR and capacitances in the battery and so it actually only charges up to 3.4V. I believe that in order to actually charge it up to 3.6V you have to use constant current charging up to 3.4V then use constant voltage charging up to 3.6V but I do not know how to implement this.

Comment: going by the graph I sent you, I recorded the current each second used when discharging. so in a form of integrating it, I simply did current*1 and added all the currents to get the area which is basically same as integrating. this came out to be 1763 A.s(C), does this seem reasonable? this is the amount discharged going from the 3.4V to the 2.5V

Comment: That works out to 490mAh which is very close to the rated capacity. However the voltage drop in the latter half of the discharge is much worse than I would have expected. Either they are poor quality cells or there was something wrong with your test setup. Usually the charger applies constant current up to 3.6V, which causes the voltage to shoot up just before the end. Charging to 3.4V still gets in the full capacity, but takes a lot longer.

Comment: @BruceAbbott If ones BMS (or lack thereof) results in running a battery down to 0V, on a regular basis, **all they need to do is use a battery which is OK with that**... NOT lithium NOT lead-acid.  NiFe and NiCd are happy as clams being run to 0V everyday... that's how cheapie solar "path lights" work.  I have a large NiCd wet-cell solar setup that is widely abused - try as they may, they can't hurt it lol.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Nicads are banned in the EU consumer market, and NiFe batteries are only available in 'industrial' sizes. For all other battery types (used in the vast majority of consumer equipment) discharging to 0V is _not_ good for them.